# Network Connection

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp

good day. I have this problem just this morning. My computer, a windows XP machine, is unable to get an IP address from the DHCP server. So what I did is assign a static IP address instead. Now, having a static IP address, it is unable to ping a local computer or connect to the internet. I was thinking that maybe it is still unable to connect to the network, so I assign an IP address that is similar to my other pc. Boom! it returns an error that there is an IP conflict(as what I have expected).

My trouble is, how come it can't get an IP address while the others can? And why is it that even if I set a static IP address, it won't allow me to connect to the internet or just even ping the other computer (which is those computers are working fine)?

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that the device which you're using has DHCP set to default by the carrier. If you are using your own personal device, like a Cisco device which you purchased, you will also have to set a DNS server(so that the computer can find routes to outside IP's) and you will have to specify the default gateway(The IP or next hop your computer will take when attempting to access resources outside of your network)

Let me know what kind of networking device you're using. If you are using a device given to you, say, by like ATT, it is their responsibility to make sure that your device can obtain an IP address. They will have to log into the device and review the configuration.

Best regards,

Comment: You should also note that unless you are a part of a large, corporate network, the DHCP is actually your core layer 3 device(networking layer). What the router will do is ACT as a DHCP server, and assign your device(s) with an IP from it's cache.                                                                                                         It's very important to note that even if you set the IP address of your DHCP server, if you did not specify the default gateway(the IP of your networking device) the computer will assume it does not have a route to the server.

Comment: It sounds to me like you did not specify the default gateway when configuring static IP on that computer. You can review the information from the other you computer(if windows) and opening/finding run.exe, which is your computer's CLI(Command LIne Interface) application. Type in ipconfig, and it will let you know what you need to know.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I have tested it out, the PC's that set to obtain an IP address works fine, they were able to get an IP address. However, this one pc can't, even though it is under one small network. When I set static IP address, I provided the default gateway and the dns as well(tried the DHCP as DNS, tried a public DNS). Still it won't allow me browse the internet or just ping the other local PC.

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1, this will test your sytem's TCP/IP stack to make sure it is configured correctly. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply.. I tried pinging 127.0.0.1 and it is just fine..

Comment: Perhaps this is outside my level of expertise. That's all I have for now. The only other thing I can suggest right now in hopes of solving your problem is to contact the vendor manager(if vendor managed/carrier managed) and asking them to resolve your DHCP issue.